# grails gebish testing loops / times

Tags: grails, groovy, geb

This is my gebish test and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
 def "create 9 more names"(){
       def i = 0
   8.times{

   $("button", value:"newCat").click()

   waitFor { $("input", name:"name") }

   $("input", name:"name") << "gebTest"
   $("input", name:"create").click()

   waitFor { $("h1", text:"Show New Name") }

   $("a", text:"new name").click()

   waitFor {$("h1.title").text() == "Names"}
   expect: at NewNamesPage
       i++
  }

}
```

This test does work:

```
 def "create name"() {

   $("button", value:"newCat").click()

   waitFor { $("input", name:"name") }

   $("input", name:"name") << "gebTest"+i
   $("input", name:"create").click()

   waitFor { $("h1", text:"Show New Name") }

   $("a", text:"new name").click()

   waitFor {$("h1.title").text() == "Names"}
   expect: at NewNamesPage

 }
```

So it seems to not like the spock block:

```
  8.times {
        //do something 8 times
   }
```

I have also tries it with a for loop.
It doesn't even start the loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: My *guess* would be that the `expect:` can't be inside a loop

Comment: That made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Also you don't need to define any variable, n.times should run the block n times. Hope that helps!

```
def "create 9 more names"(){
   def i = 0
   8.times{

   $("button", value:"newCat").click()

   waitFor { $("input", name:"name") }

   $("input", name:"name") << "gebTest"
   $("input", name:"create").click()

   waitFor { $("h1", text:"Show New Name") }

   $("a", text:"new name").click()

   waitFor {$("h1.title").text() == "Names"}
   expect: at NewNamesPage
    i += 1
  }

}
```